# Hover class apply only if element is an hyperlink

Tags: html, css, less, mixins

I was wondering when I worked on a project if I could achieve this, but assuming  it does not seem currently possible to get this behavior without any change of structure (I would really like to keep the hover inside its own class declaration), to you, what would be the cleanest solution ?

**LESS**

```
@blue: blue;
@blue-darker: darken(@blue, 20%);

.text-blue {
    color: @blue;

    /* something like that */
    &:hover when (element_reference == hyperlink) {
        color: @blue-darker;
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.text-blue {
    color: blue;
}

/* something like that */
a.text-blue:hover {
    color: #000099;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="text-blue">Text in blue with no hover effect</p>
<a class="text-blue" href="#">Link in blue with hover effect</a>
```

Comment: I presume you meant `<a class="text-blue">`?

Comment: I find the structure confusing-to me it seems like the style should be applied to links, or even links of specific classes, not to blue text when it happens to be a link. If I'm trying to find where a link style comes from that's where I'll look first-at links.

Comment: @stybl : Sorry for the typo :)

Comment: @DaveNewton: My post had an error I just fixed. You should better understand like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
.text-blue {
    color: @blue;
    a&:hover {
        color: @blue-darker;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d39f2ps5/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `:link` CSS pseudoclass, because `<a>` without `href` is not treated as a hyperlink. See at https://jsfiddle.net/jsqdom1s/

```
.text-blue {
  color: @blue;
  a&:link:hover {
    color: @blue-darker;
  }
}
```